# Установить callback на метод класса, без использования лямбды

Tags: c++, ооп

Хотелось бы использовать либо нативный указатель на метод класса, либо реализацию `std::function`, но без использования лямбды, т.е. записать коллбэк не таким способом:

```
class window : public window_base
{
private:
    std::function<void(renderer::*)()> m_display_callback_;
...
    void window::set_render_callback(renderer* rndr)
    {
        m_display_callback_ = [=]()->void{ rndr->clear(); rndr->display(); };
    }
}
```

Можно ли избежать такого вида, т.е. избавиться от лямбды?

Comment: Ничего не понял. Что вообще такое `std::function<void(renderer::*)()>` и зачем это?

Answer (score 1):

Не понял... Если статическая или свободная функция - то без проблем:

```
void f(){}

std::function<void()> m_display_callback_;

m_display_callback_ = аж
```

А если член класса - то надо учитывать, что ему передается скрытый параметр - ссылка на объект класса, так что он не может быть `void(void)`, тут надо иначе - если знать объект...

Comment: Ай, не правильно переписал, `void(renderer::*)()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void f(renderer* rndr) { rndr->clear(); rndr->display(); }

void set_render_callback(renderer* rndr)
{
    //m_display_callback_ = [=]()->void{ rndr->clear(); rndr->display(); };
    m_display_callback_ = std::bind(f, rndr);
}
```